# How to define the position that I want to my JButton on top of a background image?

Tags: java, eclipse, layout, jframe, jbutton

I have a small frame that I created and I wanted to give it an image as a background, but when I did that I tried to work with boxlayout to define the positons of the buttons.

But it was a disaster so I worked with flowlayout but the result is not what I wanted because it's different of the design in my draw. I have included the pictures of my draw and also of the result in Eclipse.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGvEr.jpg)

This is my code:

```
        import java.awt.*;
        import javax.swing.*;

        public class aceil extends JFrame {

            JPanel p4=new JPanel(),p1=new JPanel(),p2=new JPanel(),p3=new JPanel(),p=new JPanel();
            JButton cnct=new JButton(),sncr=new JButton();
            JTextField user=new JTextField(20);
            JPasswordField pass=new JPasswordField(20);
            JLabel wlcm=new JLabel(" "),j1=new JLabel("user name : "),j2=new JLabel("password : ");



            public aceil(){
                f=new formulaire();
                f.setVisible(false);

                setTitle("page d'aceile");
                setLocation(400, 350);

                cnct.addActionListener(this);
                sncr.addActionListener(this);

                cnct.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("icon.png")));
                cnct.setBorder(null);
                cnct.setMargin(null);
                sncr.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("icon2.png")));
                sncr.setBorder(null);
                sncr.setMargin(null);

                JLabel background=new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\marie\\workspace\\POAprojet\\src\\font1.png"));
                add(background);
                background.setLayout(new BoxLayout(background,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                background.add(j1);
                background.add(user);
                background.add(j2);
                background.add(pass);
                background.add(cnct);
                background.add(sncr);

                 setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 pack();
                 setVisible(true);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                new aceil();
            }
```

Comment: Do you want to put your JButton's at specified position on your JFrame?

Comment: yes at the same position as in my draw it's included  in the image that i posted with the question have u seen it ?

Comment: If you have more code changes to make, please refresh your screen first, so that you don't roll back my good edits. I have rolled back your last destructive edit, please try again. Thank you.

Comment: Amarou i think you should use the setBounds() method if you want to position your button at a specified place on JFrame.

Comment: thank you #halfer  and  #Manish_Sakpal i will try that thak you alot ^^ .